# How to force installable time-driven triggers to run only when document is opened

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently created a script associated with a spreadsheet. It is a wood supply chain simulation game score viewer. Basically, it fetch (with Urlfetch) the game database to keep track of scores for every team playing in tables and graphs. The spreadsheet is then shared to every team member, which can see the progression of the game.

So I used an installable onMinute time trigger to refresh the spreadsheet with updated score from the database. Everythings was working, but recently, I started to receive app-script-notifications of failure with error :

> Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch.

I then realised that the installable triggers are executed when the documment is not open, which is totally logic. Also, since developpement mode, I had quite a lot of the spreadsheat copy (je comprend pas sa), which explains the reach of my quota. Altough, I only need to refresh the scores for my application when the document is open.

Here are my questions :

1. Is the installable onMinute time trigger the right way to do that?
2. Is there a way to make the trigger run only when the document is open?

This is my first question here so feel free to post useful comments to allow me to improve.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can write code on the game side to push the changes to the spreadsheet, which would use less resource on both sides, a time-driven triggers seems like the only "automatic" way to go.

I say automatic, because you could change it to "on-demand". I mean, you could add a menu to your spreadsheet or an image (where you can assign to run a script on click), that will update the scores.

This could also be semi-dynamic, for example, when the user clicks the button, you start to update the scores automatically (setting up the time-driven trigger programatically) for the next 30 minutes or so.

Asking your question n.2: no, it is not possible. Well, only half-way. Because you can detect when the spreadsheet is opened (by setting a on-open trigger), but you can't know when it is closed.

Comment: Hi Henrique, wouldn't it be possible to detect if a user is 'active' on the spreadsheet with session.getUser and use this info to know if it is "open" ? (just an idea)

Comment: I *really* doubt it Serge, but I have not tested. I think that the `user` for time-driven triggers is always the account who set the trigger, regardless if he's active or not. Think on the complexity of that!? It would be something like `SpreadsheetApp.isAnyoneThere()` :)

Comment: You're probably right... I am imagining a trick though but I'll try it before and keep this post informed ;) thanks for your advice

Comment: I posted a suggestion , didn't see the other post with 2 triggers that is also an interesting suggestion... maybe I'll mix both of them ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've created an option in my menu to start the update for some hours. When the time is up it removes all the triggers. Best work arround I could find.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the onOpen event to programmatically create the following:

- a new trigger that updates the spreadsheet every minute
- a new hourly trigger that checks

  ```
  if {a user property is set} 
  then deletes all the triggers 
  else set the user property
  ```
- a onEdit trigger that unsets the previously mentioned user property

So that if a user hasn't edited the spreadsheet for an hour all the triggers stop

It's a bit convoluted but without an onClose event, convoluted is the best you can hope for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Same has above, no onEdit trigger will be fired by the users because they are not suppose to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code I imagine that could maybe do what you want or at least get close...

I tried it [on a testsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dG90MzRwX0FQUnoxTWZjcmtLSlVuT3c#gid=1) (shared with authorization requested) and it works as expected, i.e the timer triggered function executes only if someone is editing the spreadsheet, otherwise it returns.
Let's say it's a proposal, you'll tell me if it meets your requirements ;-)

```
function onTimer() { // this function has a timer trigger set to 1 minute
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AnqSFd3iikE3dG90MzRwX0FQUnoxTWZjcmtLSlVuT3c')
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var logsheet = ss.getSheets()[1]
  var formerUser = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastUser')
   if(formerUser=='nobody'){return}
     ss.toast('The sheet is being edited by '+Session.getActiveUser());
     ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastUser': 'nobody'}, true); 
     logsheet.getRange(logsheet.getLastRow()+1, 1).setValue('onTimer function was running on '+
     Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'GMT+2','HH:mm'))
}

function onUserPresent(){ // this one has an onEdit installable trigger
 ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastUser': 'someone'}, true);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking some of your time to answer my question. I think I understand your logic, but since it is just a score viewer the user doesn't edit the spreadsheet. Only the function with the one minute trigger edit it and will not fire the onEdit trigger when doing so. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: no you didn't... if the user doesn't edit the sheet it won't work. then go for the other post solution, 1 hour trigger enable, eventually renewable.